STDistance() call returning distance in meters?
I'm almost positive this snippet is returning the distance in meters, but I wanted to confirm.
DECLARE @StationCoords_Lon DECIMAL(12, 9) = -80.230679;
DECLARE @StationCoords_Lat DECIMAL(12, 9) = 25.789954;

DECLARE @MyCoords_Lon DECIMAL(12, 9) = -80.230600;
DECLARE @MyCoords_Lat DECIMAL(12, 9) =25.789951;


DECLARE @orig geography = geography::Point(@StationCoords_Lat, @StationCoords_Lon, 4326);

SELECT 
    @orig.STDistance(geography::Point(@MyCoords_Lat, @MyCoords_Lon, 4326)) 
       AS distance

Are there approximately 7.93 meters between these two points?

This question is similar to: SQL Server 2008 GEOGRAPHY STDistance() value. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The most common units of measurement of a SRID are meters or square meters. there is sys.spatial_reference_systems which show spatial_reference_id and unit_of_measure for it.


STDistance() call returning distance in meters?

As per this MS Document
The result is expressed in the unit of measure defined by the Spatial Reference Identifier (SRID) of spatial data and the most common units of measurement of a SRID are meters or square meters.
To identify the unit of measure you can use the sys.spatial_reference_systems table which shows the spatial_reference_id and its respective unit of measure.
As you are using spatial_reference_id as 4326 then your unit of measure would be meter as show in in below image:

